# Prevent users from deleting webpart

Tags: permissions

In my SharePoint Portal I have web parts. I have added users to Contribute Permission level and hence he got permission to modify the page (Edit page option) and able to delete the web part. So when another user logs in he is not able to see the web part.

I don't want the users to delete the web part even if they are in the contribute permission list. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this.

Similary, which granular permission item allows the user to edit the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are using a wiki-page. If you switch to Web Part Page or Publishing Page, I think you´r closer to your goal. It will give you the options in the web part properties to disable deleting of webparts and prevent users to edit the page.

My suggestion is solution 1, but I give you 2 other options:

Solution 1: Uncheck Allow close as David suggests. Be sure that the web part is not on a wiki-page. If so, the options is grayed out: http://summit7systems.com/web-part-advanced-options-disabled-in-sp2013/

Wiki-page also allows users to edit it

Solution 2: Open the webpart in sharepoint designer and change the xml: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f3e91255-c0e9-43a8-b4e9-3faa4c5c2e43/allow-close-and-a-couple-other-options-grayed-out-while-editing-custom-web-part?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Solution 3: Disable the options with javascript.
http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.se/2011/02/sharepoint-prevent-closing-of-web-parts.html

Answer (score 3):

Edit the web part, and uncheck Allow Close, that should stop them.

Comment: Hi David, Allow close is disabled(grayed out) for me. I have logged in with user who got full control permission level.

Comment: I think you need to login as a site collection administrator.

Comment: Hi Suryakiran, my account has site collection admin priv.

Comment: Are you in the shared view vs the personal view?

Comment: Close only hides the web part, which is insidious, because it still runs in the background. I can't understand why Microsoft hasn't removed this "feature" in later versions. Your answer is correct for Close, but not for removing a web part.